# How to use the properties query with Drive.Files.List in Google Apps Script v5

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, rhino

I'm trying to use the Advanced Google Drive service in Google Apps Script to find files with a given custom property value

```
Drive.Files.list({
          "corpora": "allDrives",
          "includeTeamDriveItems": true,
          "q": "'1tfT0BtCg2Z7B7dviOqNQsZTdSjrX5V9B' in parents and trashed = false and properties has {key='photoId' and value='AJHPqhQHfoNqbZSdk8ZUU-RILziCVXViIWPKBG46RIcTVSqzijyVOwyvk1hRE-PxCv3LGXlcT7e7AacOUjKxrUdnG6ssS4YdnQ'}",
          "supportsTeamDrives": true
        })`
```

This code as written gives the error

> API call to drive.files.list failed with error: Invalid query

however if I remove `and properties has {...}` it will run fine.

I think I need to escape the curly braces somehow however I can't quite figure out how to do so?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`visibility` parameter is not optional in v2. Use

```
`
'1tfT0BtCg2Z7B7dviOqNQsZTdSjrX5V9B' in parents and
 trashed = false and
 properties has {
    key='photoId' and 
    value='AJHPqhQHfoNqbZSdk8ZUU-RILziCVXViIWPKBG46RIcTVSqzijyVOwyvk1hRE-PxCv3LGXlcT7e7AacOUjKxrUdnG6ssS4YdnQ' and 
    visibility='PRIVATE'
 }
`
```

Comment: Oh my god how did I not see that in the docs :facepalm:

THANK YOU!!